# Problem with projection of Slovenian Shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, wgs84, slovenia

I hope someone can help me for this:
I'm doing my masters thesis in Slovenia (in the field of wildlife management), for this I got a Shapefile of slovenian data by the University. As a main layer, I use CORINELandCover and World borders ([TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php)) in WGS84. When I import the slovenian layer (Data layer strictly confidential, but exactly the same problem when I import this layer: [Grid 100m x 100m.zip](http://www.stat.si/GIS/baza.aspx?lang=en)), it absolutely doesn't match the location where it should be projected on the CORINE- and WorldBorder-layer. I'don't know the coordinate system of the slovenian shapes, but when importet into QGIS, it tells me that it's WGS84, which cannot be true, because when I zoom to the slovenian layer, the coordinates shown in the "Current map coordinate" (right, down) are definitely not WGS84 (it gives me the following extends: 342637,26823 : 656728,197123).

I have no idea what the problem is, maybe QGIS doesn't know this coordinate system, but in this case, shouldn't it report an error message regarding this?

Comment: The .prj file that comes together with shapefile package defines the projection. In this case it seems to be custom `"Slovenia (D-48 Slovenia) 3-parameters", 8, 999, 10, 668, -205, 472, 7, 15, 0, 0.9999, 500000, -5000000`. QGIS may not know how to reproject it correctly. You can try to save the PRJ definition from here http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7326/ on disk and use it instead of the .prj file you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .prj file is definitely wrong, it should contain a WKT definition. It looks rather like a mapinfo projection definition file.

Try `EPSG:3787 MGI Slovene National Grid` or `EPSG:3912 MGI 1901 / Slovene National Grid`. They differ in the datum shift.

[image]